# access vue environment variables in template

Tags: html, vue.js, templates, environment-variables

I want to access my environment variables from the template of vue single file components
however, doing the following:

```
<img :src="`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL}/image/${image.filename}`" alt="" />
```

gives me the error:

```
 Property or method "process" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property
```

i know my environment variables are set up correctly as i can use them in other places, and i can use a workaround to create a new variable on the component and reference that:

```
data() {
  return {
    BaseUrl: process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL,
  };
},

<img :src="`${BaseUrl}/image/${image.filename}`" alt="" />
```

and that is able to load the image correctly, but how can i access the env variables directly in the template without the need to initialise a new variable for each component?

Comment: Are you serverside rendering with Nuxt.js?

Comment: that is because process is global, but in template are used local vars (like there is this. before them), so you could define computed prop for example $process: process, so it could be used in template placeholders.

Comment: @TJ no this is a spa

Comment: @willystyle is there a way to load it into all components automatically? so i don't have to define it individually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`process.env` environment variables are replaced with actual values at compilation time. The error means that this doesn't happen in templates.

Things can be defined [globally](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-config.html#globalproperties) for all components, e.g. for Vue 2:

```
Vue.prototype.$baseUrl = process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL;
```

Putting too much code into templates is a bad practice. In this case image URL can be defined as `computed`, or as `method` for `image` provided by `v-for`.

Answer (score 4):

For Vue3 in the `main.js` file you can write:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
const app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.$myVariable = process.env.VUE_APP_MY_VARIABLE;
```

And then access in every template:

```
<template>
  My variable is: {{ $myVariable }}
</tempate>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 3 + Vite + TypeScript, I did not need to use `globalProperties` or any other magic. Any environment variables defined in the `.env` file are directly accessible in the SFC. Just create a `ref` (or `computed`) in your `script` section like this:

```
const BaseUrl = ref<string>(import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL)
```

and then use it in your `template` section. Remember that the variable name must start with the string `VITE_` for this to work.