# Vue - How to remove lines from template in the bundled code?

Tags: vue.js, templates, environment-variables

Is there a way to remove lines **from the template** so the relevant lines **aren't compiled** and doesn't exist in bundled code??

I have defined environment vars in .env file, and I want them to secure some of my code, so after using the build with definePlugin there are no remains that can be found in the minified file for some lines of code.
i.e: using VUE_APP_SECRET=false and then in code :

```
if(process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET == 'true'){..}
```

This works great on JS part, and the relevant lines doesn't exist in the minified file.

But in .vue file on the template section I have tried to do it using v-if and the relevant line still appear in the minified file. (I used a data member for process.env and accessed it from the v-if as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67460342/access-vue-environment-variables-in-template)):

```
<div v-if="globalEnv.VUE_APP_SECRET =='true'"> here goes some secured text </div>

data() {
  return {
    globalEnv: process.env,
  };
},
```

Is there a solution for removing some parts of the template in certain builds ??

Answer (score 0):

Save your Booleans as numbers 0 or 1 and use Number() to convert it.

```
<div v-if="Number(globalEnv.VUE_APP_SECRET)"> here goes some secured text</div>
```

And in your .env use:

```
VUE_APP_SECRET=1
```

Comment: I don't see how it would help. The v-if is working ok, I don't see the line in the application. The problem is the compiled code still have these lines, it's not removed during the build, like it is done with JS code.

Comment: i don't know if thats possible in Vue. Maybe you could try generating your template with JS.

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed property in your template

```
<div v-if="myprop"> here goes some secured text 
</div>

computed:
  myprop() {
    return process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET === 'true'
  }
},
```

Comment: But it's the same idea as using data.. This still keep the code of the template in the compiled app.js file..

Comment: I have edited the question title so it would be more clear ..

Comment: aah.. I understand. You may need to fiddle with vue-loader or webpack for this.